# Button loops to generate multiple Jquery datepickers

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, button, datepicker

I've been working with this jquery datepicker example here.
https://jsfiddle.net/jakecigar/Lkqopvc8/5/

I've got a button, that has a javascript function which is called. It is suppose to ideally, generate a new datepicker every time it's clicked.
I can generate 3 input type='text', but none of them work with jquery datepicker.
If I change input type='date', that works, but it's not a jquery datepicker.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

PS. You can ignore the global var variables, that's just for keeping a limit on the number of datepickers created.

Here is my JS/HTML/JQuery code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


  <script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css">

<style id="compiled-css" type="text/css">

#date-list{


    list-style:none;

</style>

</head>
<body>

<center>    
    <button onclick = "countButton()">Count</button>
<ul id = "date-list">

</ul>

    </center>

  <script type="text/javascript">

//GLOBAL VARIABLES


var ul = document.getElementById("date-list");  
var dateIds = ["datepicker1", "datepicker2", "datepicker3"]; 
var dateIdsHash = ["#datepicker1", "#datepicker2", "#datepicker3"];
var dateNumbers = ["1", "2", "3"]; 
var count = 0;  
var dateNumbersCounted;   
var dateIdsCounted;

function countButton(){


for(var i =0; i < 3; i++){

    ul.innerHTML += "<li class='my-date'>Date " + 
    dateNumbers[i] + 
    " <input type='text'></li><br>";


}; 


var tags = document.getElementsByTagName("input");      

for(var j = 0; j < tags.length; j++){

    tags[j].id = dateIds[j];

$.datepicker.setDefaults({
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
  //  any more global options from Datepicker Widget | jQuery UI API Documentation
})

$(dateIdsHash[i]).datepicker();

};    


}   

</script>

  <script>
    // tell the embed parent frame the height of the content
    if (window.parent && window.parent.parent){
      window.parent.parent.postMessage(["resultsFrame", {
        height: document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height,
        slug: "Lkqopvc8"
      }], "*")
    }

    // always overwrite window.name, in case users try to set it manually
    window.name = "result"
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two issues in your code. Firstly you don't provide the `input` elements you create with any `id` attribute, so your selector fails. Secondly, the second loop iterates over `j`, not `i`, so the last line should be `$(dateIdsHash[j]).datepicker();`. Tyr this:

```js
var ul = document.getElementById("date-list");
var dateIds = ["datepicker1", "datepicker2", "datepicker3"];
var dateIdsHash = ["#datepicker1", "#datepicker2", "#datepicker3"];
var dateNumbers = ["1", "2", "3"];
var count = 0;
var dateNumbersCounted;
var dateIdsCounted;

function countButton() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    ul.innerHTML += "<li class='my-date'>Date " + dateNumbers[i] + " <input type='text' id='" + dateIdsHash[i].replace('#', '') + "'></li><br>";
  };

  var tags = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for (var j = 0; j < tags.length; j++) {
    tags[j].id = dateIds[j];
    $.datepicker.setDefaults({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
      //  any more global options from Datepicker Widget | jQuery UI API Documentation
    })
    $(dateIdsHash[j]).datepicker();
  };
}
```

```css
#date-list {
  list-style: none;
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css">

<center>
  <button onclick="countButton()">Count</button>
  <ul id="date-list"></ul>
</center>
```

That being said, you can make this logic much more succinct if you use jQuery methods.

```js
var $ul = $("#date-list");
var $countButton = $('#count').on('click', function() {
  var li = (new Array(3)).fill('<li class="my-date">Date <input type="text" /></li>');
  $ul.append(li);
  $('.my-date input').datepicker();
});
```

```css
#date-list {
  list-style: none;
}
.my-date {
  margin: 0 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css">

<center>
  <button id="count">Count</button>
  <ul id="date-list"></ul>
</center>
```

Comment: Thanks, I just realized I should have put datesIdHash[j], not datesIdHash[i], was a typo! Thanks for the solution though!

Comment: No problem. I just updated the answer for you to include a much more succinct jQuery version which also removes the need for the iterative `id` attributes, which are an anti-pattern and should be avoided.